# My sql results from rows to column

Tags: mysql

is there a way to insert some values of the COUNT(*) into these columns. To explain. I have a table

```
   +--------+----------+
   | url    |   type   |
   +--------+----------+
   |   URl1 |    A     |  
   +--------+----------+
   |   URL1 |    B     |  
   +--------+----------+
   |   URL2 |    C     |  
   +--------+----------+
   |   URL2 |    C     |  
   +--------+----------+
```

where the values is how many times the type (A,B,C) appears in the data set (this is why i want to COUNT)
i want to have something like this at my final table

```
   +--------+------+-----+-----+
   | url    |   A  |  B  |  C  |
   +--------+------+-----+-----+
   |   URL1 |   3  |  1  |  0  |
   +--------+------+-----+-----+
   |   URL2 |   2  |  0  |  1  |
   +--------+------+-----+-----+
```

Until now i did this

```
SELECT 
   url, type, COUNT(*)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY url,type
```

and i'm getting this (random example)

```
|url      |type |COUNT of a specific type for this url|
https://1   A    1
https://2   A    1
https://2   B    1
https://3   B    1
https://4   C    4
https://4   B    2
https://4   B    2
```

and i want to insert the values like the table above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case when and group by

```
  select  url,
          sum(case when type ='A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
          sum(case when type ='B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
          sum(case when type ='C' then 1 else 0 end) as C      
  FROM my_table
  group by url ;
```

Comment: Thans for the fast answer it worked. I was trying something like this but with COUNT

Comment: thanks  .. in these case the use of case .. when  .. is very useful ..